# Convert a list into chunks of increasing size

Tags: python, list

How could I convert a list into a nested list with increasing size of the sublists?

For example,
from

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

to

```
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: that supposes that the length of the list is of the form (n+1)*n // 2 for starters. Is there something you tried?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: By writing some code. How do you decide the length of each sub-array? Would a list `[2,3,4]` get split in `[[2,3],[4]]`? If the sequence of lengths is 1,2,3... what happens with the last element if these do not add up?

Comment: this could help (with adaptation): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's unclear how odd-length lists should be handled. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this with [islices](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) over an iterator of the original list. This way I can just specifiy the number of elements to take without having to worry at which position I am currently at. (In addition, the following code works with any iterable.)

```
def increasing_chunks(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    i = 1

    while True:
        chunk = list(islice(it, i))
        if not chunk:
            break
        yield chunk
        i += 1
```

The last chunk might be truncated to whatever amount of elements the iterator had left.

Demo:

```
>>> list(increasing_chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> list(increasing_chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

If you want to discard truncated chunks, adjust the code as follows:

```
def increasing_chunks_strict(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    i = 1

    while True:
        chunk = list(islice(it, i))
        if len(chunk) < i:
            break
        yield chunk
        i += 1
```

Now, truncated chunks are not included in the result.

```
>>> list(increasing_chunks_strict([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> list(increasing_chunks_strict([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to [timgeb's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53364812/1822698), without `itertools`, you need to keep track of the index:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

i, slice_length = 0, 1
result = []
while i < len(l):
    result.append(l[i:i + slice_length])
    i += slice_length
    slice_length += 1

print(result)
# [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Several [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to the rescue:

```
from itertools import count, accumulate as acc, takewhile as tw

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[lst[c:c+i] for i, c in enumerate(tw(lambda x: x < len(lst), acc(count())), 1)]
# [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you list length has the correct length for the last chunk to have the correct size, you can use list `sum`, `range` and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to solve your problem in few lines:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
slices = range(1, (len(l) + 1)/2 + 1)
result = [l[sum(slices[:s-1]):sum(slices[:s-1])+s] for s in slices]
```